# mysql search optimization with hex function

Tags: mysql

I have a INNODB table and need to search in a VARCHAR column but searching is very very slow. I cannot add a FULLTEXT index :( and MYISAM is not an option.

Some guys gave me advice to use HEX like the code below.
Is that right? Does it perform better? I don't see any progress in my application.

```
SELECT *
FROM order_line
WHERE HEX(description) LIKE '%6B616C6B7A616E64737465656E%'
```

Comment: I can't think of any reason for this performing better. Also as of MySQL 5.6 you can use FULLTEXT indexes on InnoDB.

Comment: Used function in condition? => (99%) No index used

Comment: This will not perform better, and will very likely perform worse.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the table in question requires InnoDB and you are restricted to an outdated MySQL version for some reason, there are at least two possible improvements (and a third that builds on one of them):

1. Copy the primary key(s) and the searchable text column(s) into a MyISAM table with a fulltext index and run the searches against that. This will obviously require you to update the search table every time the original is updated.
2. You can create cache tables storing information about the executed searches and their hits for later reuse (one to track the cached searches and the other to cache the actual results). Again, this will require you to periodically update the cache or purge it completely.
3. Since you're using LIKE to search, you could use solution #2 with an additional hack: first check if there are cached searches for substrings of the current search query and limit the scope of your search to items that matched those previous searches only.

Comment: hi .. thx for your answer, i'm working on point 2 now .. hopefully it works for my app